# how to pass two object values to single Temp Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

TempData["Amalgamation"] = SearchList;
 I am using this code already in this TempData a record is there now i want to append new data which was stored in "SearchList". How can i do that?

Comment: What is typeof `SearchList`?

Comment: 1) What is typeof SearchList?
2) Where are you get new data for store in SearchList??

Comment: SearchList = objSearch.CompanyAmalgamateList;

Comment: SearchList type is List

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `SearchList` is a `List<T>`

```
var searchList = (List<SomeType>)TempData["Amalgamation"];
searchList.Add(...);
```

Comment: "Type Caste" Error is occuring.

Comment: @PrudhvirajPallam you need to cast it to the correct type, my answer is just an example of how it would be done with a `List<T>`.

Comment: how to cast system.generic.list to "Amalgamation" list

Comment: i can't get that one can you explain briefly please

Comment: Is there anyone to help me please

Comment: @PrudhvirajPallam sorry but your question has been answered, you have given absolutely no code example. The above is how you cast from `object` to a `List<T>` (`T` being `SomeType` in this example). If you have `List<T>` in your application then all you need to do is replace `T` with the type you are actually using, I can't really put it any simpler.

Comment: I have done same thing but it is asking to cast from my own type to Collection.generic.list how can i cast that one

Comment: like "Amalgamation" is my model's list and i am getting some data from database and storing all those data in TempData but now i have to append new data to That Tempdata                                             SearchList = objSearch.CompanyAmalgamateList ;                                          like this

Comment: @PrudhvirajPallam when you say "*cast from my own type*" what is your *own type* in this example?

Comment: 'RDB.BusinessRegistration.Model.Amendment.Amalgamation'

Comment: @PrudhvirajPallam that would suggest that `searchList` isn't a list at all, it's an instance of `Amalgamation`. If you are storing an instance of `Amalgamation` in the `TempData` then you will need to cast it to just that, not `List<Amalgamation>`... your question is confusing & the example doesn't help as it's not what it is expected to be.